# Issues while using SmartCard Authentication Token (Watchdata proxkey) in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, certificates

I am trying to install SmartCard token Driver(Watchdata proxkey) in ubuntu 22.04.The driver downloaded from emudra site:https://www.e-mudhra.com/repository/
and NICDSign.deb Downloaded from https://www.info.spark.gov.in/?page_id=1501.  After Driver installation,we cannot access the token because failed to fetch the token configuration details.kindly help to resolve the following issue.Please note that same device,driver combination working with ubuntu 18,04 and 20.04

Comment: https://rurban.gov.in/NICDSign/Installation%20Instructions-Ubuntu.pdf

Comment: we already follow these steps...but not working in ubuntu 22.04...

Comment: Does proxykey show in NICDSign's settings? can you please confirm

Comment: yes,Proxkey is showing in NICDSign settings

Comment: I too had some issues with NICDSign. I made use of the question regarding the same issue in 
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+question/704089 I considered the concluding part of that thread and tried.  It is working in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS also if it is an updated version.